# Invalid Signature Code object is not signed at all for Pythonista

Tags: python, iphone, xcode, frameworks

I am working on a project where I need to use Python to execute a script on my iPhone App. I have used [Pythonista](https://github.com/omz/PythonistaAppTemplate)   to execute the python script on an iPhone App. The app works as expected on the simulator and actual device however when I try uploading build to AppStore it gives me error on Pythonist framework **Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all.**

[image: Sign error Pythonista]

I have been through almost every post on StackOverflow and other blogs but nothing worked for me. If anyone has implemented Pythonista and successfully released the app on AppStore can help me.

I have put [my code here.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g4sdzoruzldhntb/AACCyDAiIHeH1-h4kBPj6dsNa?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common error and I find it's often caused by `Info.plist` being misconfigured.

Check `CFBundleExecutable` matches the name of the executable and that `CFBundleName` matches the name of the bundle and that `CFBundleIdentifier` is valid.

If you have frameworks or `.dylib`s in the bundle, which are not properly signed, you can sometimes solve the issue by adding `--deep` to the *Other Code Sign Flags* variable in *Build Settings*.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I somehow managed to make it working during upload process using Python3 framework, however after uploading the build I received apples email that your app is rejected due to the same CODE OBJECT IS NOT SIGNED AT ALL. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g4sdzoruzldhntb/AABd4ajVP4x-szA02U_vOiCma/App%20Delivery%20Error.png?dl=0